# How to set socketWriteTimeout in Ignite Config

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to set SocketWriteTimeout using config but it is giving error in red as follows-

[image]

Programmatically, I can set it very easily like this-

```
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = ignite.configuration();
    TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    commSpi.setSocketWriteTimeout(getSocketWriteTimeout());
    igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);
```

Comment: Illegible. You can see for yourself. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

Should be *<property name="**socket**WriteTimeout" ...* I suppose?